# Not able to call method of dll from JavaFX application

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing a JavaFX application & a C++ dll whose method i want to call from JavaFX (java code). So, i have placed the dll in project directory, getting the working directory during runtime , hence creating the path to dll , setting the same path value to "java.library.path" & then loading the dll in static block. After loading when i am trying to access method of dll , everytime I am getting "Unsatisfied LinkError".

Please guide me with the above issue. Whether JavaFX JNI application works ??

Following is code :

```
package jni;
 
public class Test{
 
    static {
        try {
            System.out.println("Current Directory :" + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\dll";
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
            System.loadLibrary("Test");
            System.out.println("Loaded DLL");
            System.out.println("java.library.path : " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex) {
            System.out.println("\n Link Issue :" + ex.getStackTrace());
        } finally {
 
        }
 
    }
 
    public static native void nativeTest();
 
    public static void NativeTestJni() {
        try {
            System.out.println("\n Called Frm MEthod");
            nativeTest();
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex) {
            System.out.println("\n Erase Called from Method");
        } finally {
 
        }
 
    }
 
}

package xyz;
 
import jni.Test
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
 
public class TestJNI extends Application {
 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("My First JavaFX App");
 
        primaryStage.show();
 
        Test.NativeTestJni();
        System.out.println("\n called ended frm obj");
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);       
    }
 
 }
```

I am getting correct value for the path of library which I am printing. Bt when I am trying to call method of DLL it says

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptio Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jni.Test.nativeTest()V

Please help me with the above issue , in dll i am only printing a "Hello". Its nt comimg up.

Updating the C++ code :
generated header file using javah on Test class & hence wrote cpp code accordingly.

### Header File : jni_Test.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jni_Test */

#ifndef _Included_jni_Test
#define _Included_jni_Test
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jni_Test
 * Method:    nativeTest
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jni_Test_nativeTest
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

### C++ File : jni_Test.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "jni_Test.h"
using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jni_Test_nativeTest
(JNIEnv *, jclass){
    std::cout << "Hello JNI !!";
    printf("Hello JNI Print !!!!!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: The error message indicates that it's not the library that can't be loaded but that the runtime doesn't find a matching function in the library for `nativeTest`. Post your C code. Make sure you've created your header with `javah` to eliminate typos etc.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I created header file using javah only. I have updated above the C++ code for dll. Please review & let me know if I have missed anything.

Comment: The function might not be exported. Did you define the JNIEXPORT symbol when building the DLL? (Still assuming that your static initilializer runs without printing that "Link Issue" message, because you would have mentioned that, right?)

Comment: Yes you are right I am not getting "Link Issue" message in static block. On calling the method of dll after load "Link Issue" is coming.

Comment: So, did you remember to define the symbol? Check if the function is exported with some tool (like Dependency Walker)

Comment: Ok, forget that. `jni_md.h` defines the symbol.

Comment: Here's another idea. You can't change `java.library.path` once the program is running. It has to be provided with `-D`. It didn't seem to be your problem, because `loadLibrary` didn't complain, but maybe there's another (wrong) version of the library on your PATH that gets loaded instead of the one you want.